# How to monitor a service running on an EC2 instance using Cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I am running a service on an EC2 instance(running on RHEL), and usually I would do a status check using ./<service_name> status, which would return "running" or "not running" as output.
How do I set this up in Amazon cloudwatch to trigger an alarm when the service is not running?

Answer (score -1):

[image: ec2 start / stop instances]

You need to set the ec2 start and stop instances separately to check the status as per the output received.